# Running clang64.exe or mingw64.exe incorrectly sets PATH

Tags: path, msys2

I have MSYS2 installed on my Windows computer. The installation package includes files such as mingw64.exe, clang64.exe, and others. According to this [page](https://www.msys2.org/docs/environments/), when running the corresponding executable file, we expect to use the appropriate environment.

However, in my case there is the following oddity:

1. Run `mingw64.exe` -> $ `echo $PATH` out is `/clang64/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/c/Windows/System32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl`
2. Run `clang64.exe` -> $ `echo $PATH` out is `/clang64/bin:/clang64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/c/Windows/System32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl`
3. Run `clangarm64.exe` -> $ `echo $PATH` out is `/clang64/bin:/clangarm64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/c/Windows/System32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl`

Thus, one way or another the **clang** compiler will be used, which is completely **not expected**

****UPDATE****

According to the recommendations of ChatGPT, I tested the `$MSYSTEM` variable:

1. Run `mingw64.exe` -> `echo $MSYSTEM` -> MINGW64
2. Run `clang64.exe` -> `echo $MSYSTEM` -> CLANG64

The result is *correct*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not normal to have `/clang64/bin` on your PATH when you run `mingw64.exe`.  There must be a [startup script](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html) somewhere that is adding it.

Run the following command to look for any mentions of `clang64` in the startup scripts:

```
grep -n clang64 /etc/profile /etc/profile.d/* ~/.bash_profile ~/.bash_login ~/.profile ~/.bashrc
```

If that doesn't illuminate anything, you might have to look more carefully at those scripts to see what they are doing.  You can also try putting `echo $PATH` commands at various points in those scripts to debug them.

Comment: After running `grep -n clang64 /etc/profile /etc/profile.d/* ~/.bash_profile ~/.bash_login ~/.profile ~/.bashrc`, I received  `grep: /home/Pavel/.bash_login: No such file or directory
/home/Pavel/.bashrc:191:export PATH=/clang64/bin:$PATH` After that, in the `\home\Pavel.bashrc`, I commented out this line. Now the problem is completely solved, thanks a lot